# Angular2 - Assign "ngClass" to the current element only

Tags: angular

I want to assign `ngClass` only the element being clicked; however, it gets assigned to all the other elements.

**.html**

```
    <div class="likeBtn" (click)="like()" [ngClass]="{'likeBtnClicked': clicked}" item-right>I like</div>
```

**.ts**

```
like(){
clicked = true;
}
```

Comment: Are the other elements bound to the same 'ngClass' expression ({'likeBtnClicked': clicked})?

Comment: @snorkpete yes, exactly!

Answer (score 0):

here is html:

```
<div class="likeBtn" (click)="like(like1.id)"  #like1 id="1"
    [ngClass]="{'likeBtnClicked':  likes[like1.id]}" item-right>I like</div>

  <div class="likeBtn" (click)="like(like2.id)" #like2 id="2"
        [ngClass]="{'likeBtnClicked': likes[like2.id]}" item-right>I like</div>
```

`

and here is component that has map of likes and method to add new like:

```
 export class App {
  likes = {};

  like(id) {
   this.likes[id] = true;
  }
 }
```